# CoreData Concurrency Exception with batch insert

Tags: swift, core-data

I've run into an issue while debugging CoreData application with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` for a batch insert. I create a task context and just after it, make the batch insert request. Despite being in the same thread where context was created, the debugger flags it's doing multi threading violation. In the following code example, `batchInsertV1` raises exception while `batchInsertV2` works fine.

```swift
actor DataStore {

  // This function raises excepion
  nonisolated func batchInsertV1(objects: [[String: Any]]) {
    guard !objects.isEmpty else { return }

    // 1 - context is created here
    let context = Persistence.shared.bgContext
    let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entityName: "<EntityName>", objects: objects)
    batchInsertRequest.resultType = .statusOnly

    do {
      // 2 - This line raises multi threading exception with concurrency debug flag
      try context.execute(batchInsertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }

  // This function has no exception
  nonisolated func batchInsertV2(objects: [[String: Any]]) async {
    guard !objects.isEmpty else { return }

    let context = Persistence.shared.bgContext

    let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entityName: "<EntityName>", objects: objects)
    batchInsertRequest.resultType = .statusOnly

    // 3 - Wrapping it around perform block does not raise an exception. But why? context is created on thread. Shouldnt get get executed on same queue?
    await context.perform {
      do {
        // 2 - This line raises exception with concurrency debug flag
        try context.execute(batchInsertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult
      } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }

  }
}

class Persistence {
  static let shared = Persistence()
  var bgContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    let context = storeContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return context
  }

  private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer
}
```

Given the context is created and executed on same thread, why does `context.execute` raises multi threading exception?

Comment: Can you clarify a few code comments? Before `batchInsertV2`, there is a code comment that says “this function has no exception”, but later, inside that function, says “this line raises exception with concurrency debug flag”.

Comment: Also, are we to infer that the `backgroundContext` referenced in `batchInsertV1` and `batchInsertV2` are the `bgContext` defined in `Persistence`? And did you mean to make `bgContext` a computed property (i.e., one that returns a new background context every time you reference it)? I would have thought that you’d want a stored property initialized by a closure, not a computed property.

Comment: I think that the context returned by the `newBackgroundContext()` method does not operate on the queue it was created on, but rather on a private queue, that's why you must use `perform` or `performAndWait`.

Comment: @Rob `bgContext` is a computed variable. It's meant to be used by each individual task operating on different threads.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev That seems to be the case. Even though the `context` is created at the same thread, the execution context remains at a different queue for the `ManagedObject`. So we'll need to access MO's properties or any updates inside `perform` blocks.

Comment: “`bgContext` is a computed variable. It's meant to be used by each individual task operating on different threads.” … yes, inferred that. I guess I was being too obtuse: (a) you don’t use this computed property anywhere (but perhaps that was a typo, what you reference as `backgroundContext`, elsewhere); and (b) IMHO, it is very a bad idea (an anti-pattern) to have a computed property that creates a new instance every time you reference it.

Comment: @Rob Okay that was my bad (a) was a typo and I fixed it in the code above. 

(b) Noted. Can be easily extracted to a function instead. `func getBackgroundContex() -> NSManagedObjectContext` ...  Is that a better approach for improving the anti pattern

Comment: Yep, or perhaps even better, `createBackgroundContext()` which makes it clear what is really going on, namely that you are not just retrieving (some possibly existing) context, but creating a new one on every call. Sorry to dwell on something so minor. ;)